# Highcharts export function not working on Android/IOS App built from Ionic but working on desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, highcharts, ionic2

Good day,

I have an Android/IOS app built from **ionic2** with **Highcharts** export functionality. This function works perfectly on Desktop Browsers but, after building it as Android and IOS Application it didn't work.

I already imported the `exporting.js` and the `offline-exporting.js` on the ts file. And also added the highcharts dependency on the `package.json`.

Any idea why I'm encountering this problem?
Does any of you encountered the  same problem too?

Comment: Everything works fine in pure JS Highcharts on my android device. Please provide a live demo of your code (jsfiddle ideally) and specification of your browser.

Comment: @KamilKulig are you using Ionic? I have the same problem. Everything works well in desktop browser.

Comment: No, I tested it in pure Highcharts (no ionic).